# Kubernetes Liveness and readiness probes causing error logs 'http: TLS handshake error from 10.234.0.1:49330: EOF'

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, logging, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

I am configuring readiness and liveness probes for my kuberenetes deployment.

Here is how i added it:

```
  ports:
    - name: http
      containerPort:  {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
      protocol: TCP
  livenessProbe:
    tcpSocket:
      port: http
  readinessProbe:
    tcpSocket:
      port: http
```

But this is causing the error logs in the pod:

```
2021/03/24 03:23:06 http: TLS handshake error from 10.244.0.1:48476: EOF
```

If i remove the probes and create the deployment, this logs will not appear.

I have an ingress setup such that  all the http requests to that container as https. Because my container expects only https requests to it.

I thought this error logs are shown because the tcp probes are not sending https requests here.

Is there some other way to setup probes without these error logs?

Answer (score 3):

if you are looking forward to send to the HTTPS request to the service you have to change the `scheme`.

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: 443
    scheme: HTTPS
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: 443
    scheme: HTTPS
```

you can check more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#http-probes

scheme: Scheme to use for connecting to the host (HTTP or HTTPS). Defaults to HTTP.

if HTTPS is set **kubelet** will send to HTTPS request or else by default it will be HTTP.

if request if failing you will see logs like : 400 bad request

```
10.165.18.52 - - [24/March/2021:17:06:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 271 "-" "kube-probe/1.16"
```

for the successful request, it will be **200** request

```
10.165.18.52 - - [24/March/2021:18:10:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 "-" "kube-probe/1.16"
```